# Regex keeps finding character I want matched along with previous character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following regex in `javascript` for a split operation since I can't do a negative look behind to find any delimiters `,` in a string that is not proceeded by one or more escape characters of `\`.

`[^\\],`

The regex works fine for finding where the commas not proceeded by `\` are, but also finds the character that proceeds the comma as a match and thus splits the string incorrectly.

For example if I had the string

`hello\,there,are`

The result would be that `e,` matches my regex and not just `,`. Making the split string array read

`[hello\,ther] [are]`

Why does the regex I am using keep finding the comma and the proceeding character instead of only matching the comma?

Comment: Because your reges consists of 2 characters. 1st character it will find is anything that is not a backslash and 2nd character will be a comma.

Comment: @anubhava is right, your regex matches anything but `\\` before the comma.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, thats what I thought. Is there anyway in javascript other then reversing the string to have accomplish my goal?

Comment: You cannot use `split` here because you'd need a lookbehind that JS regex does not support. Use a `match` with appropriate regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `split` here because you'd need a lookbehind that JS regex does not support. Use a match with appropriate regex.  Like the one below:

```
/(?:[^\\,]|\\.)+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FgtivL/1).

The pattern matches 1 or more (`+`) sequences of any char other than `,` and `\` (`[^\\,]`) or (`|`) any escaped character (excluding linebreak chars) with `\\.`

JS demo:

```js
var regex = /(?:[^\\,]|\\.)+/g;
var str = "hello\\,there,are";
var res = str.match(regex);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hang on... how is this accepted? It doesn't work if you use `string.split()`

Comment: @musefan `.split()` does not work, but `.match()` still returns an array, as the OP requested.